# Chrome Developer Tools Profiler showing different number of method calls vs console.log

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, performancecounter

I'm using the Profiles tab of the Dev Tools in Chrome.  In the profile, I'm seeing an entry for function `resizeDocument` called 6+ times, with values 113ms, 17ms, 45ms, etc etc.  Same line number, same file, same everything.

When I log from the console inside `resizeDocument` function, I only get one entry.  What is going on?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I notice there is an "aggregated total time" there, which is the same in each case.  Perhaps there is some internal V8 weirdness happening and the stack trace is getting munged?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason of that is the nature of CPU profiler in chrome. It is a sampling profiler. So it collects call stacks (samples) of the running program and uses them for reconstructing the bars in the chart view.

For example if the profiler collected 1000 samples with one call frame for a function 'foo' in the each sample then you will see 1s long bar with 'foo' name in it.

It might happen that the profiler can't collect the next stack trace. For example it happens when the profiler tries to collect the call frames from the stack at a time when the function 'foo' called function 'bar' right before the sample. At this moment, right after call instruction, the function 'bar' constructs the call frame for 'foo' on the stack. So the call frames on the stack are in invalid state at the moment. The profiler detects that and drops the sample. As a result a gap happens in the sequence of stack traces.

In this case two different bars for 'foo' will be constructed.

Also there is a few other reasons when the profiler can't collect the call stack.

Comment: Thanks for this.  So there is no way (without console.log) of verifying that two bars in the profiler was actually not two function calls?

Comment: yep. The instrumenting profiler which has such a guaranties screw the performance of the app to much more than the sampling profiler. So no one needs the data that doesn't reflect the real situation.